# dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(context) returns null when the sql table is empty

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

I have this following function to convert table data to XML. However, whenever the table data is null the resulting XML is null. I want it to add the column names in case of empty table data.
What changes should I make in this function.

```
function XmlToBlob(p_query varchar2) return blob is 
  ctx         dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
  xml         xmltype;
  resultBlob  blob; 
begin
  ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(p_query);
  dbms_xmlgen.setNullHandling(ctx, dbms_xmlgen.empty_tag);
  xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(ctx);
  if (xml is not null) then
    resultBlob := xml.getBlobVal(NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8'));
  else
    resultBlob := null;
  end if;
  return resultBlob;
end;
```

Comment: Are you suggestion a resulting xml with "null values"?

Comment: XML with just the tags for column names. Actually I am exporting this XML to .xls file later on. And it creates 0kb file which doesn't open. I want this .xls (generated from this xml) to atleast contain the column names so it can open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query so that it will return a single row of null values if no other data can be retrieved.

Try this:

FOR ORACLE:

```
select emp.*
from   dual
left   join emp on ( 1 = 1 )
```

FOR MSSQL SERVER:

```
select t.*
from (select 1 as adummy) a
left join (select * from emp ) t on 1=1
```

Comment: the query at the moment is simply "select * from emp"

Comment: seems great! I'll mark it as answer as soon as I test it.

Comment: hey! how do I write this query for SQL Server to return at least 1 row?

Comment: Not sure - does SQL Server support the "with" syntax? If so you can simply make your own dual. Else just create your own single-row-table and call it whatever you like.

Comment: i did it. Its updated in your answer. Thanks for your help though!